# How to automate DropBox startup without logging in

Tags: launchd, dropbox

I'd like to have DropBox running under multiple user accounts on a Mac, even after a reboot. The Mac auto logs in as one user, not me. How to best achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to configure Dropbox identically for all users, at least to the extent of "start at login", and "save password/login information". But if you configure it for all the system users, it should work identically no matter who logs in.

Comment: I realize that auto login might be disabled at some point. Would this method work then?

Comment: No. Without a logged user, you cannot coerce Dropbox to work with it's current design. Period.

Comment: Why not?  You can do it under Linux.

Comment: Mac isn't Linux

Answer (score 0):

Create a script and it in `/Library/StartupItems`?  You may also be able to simply drop an alias in that folder.

Comment: Any advice what might be in that script?

Comment: I think it can be a simple script (make sure to chmod +x it), with a one-liner that runs DropBox.  I'm really not sure, but I would try 'open /Applications/Dropbox.app/' or what have you.

Comment: This won't work because it will present the login screen for the app if it's not already configured/saved permanently. If, per my answer, you configure/save it for everyone, then it will work (but at that point, it will likely be logging in automatically anyways).